# Google Chrome 65 CORS issue

Tags: api, google-chrome, asp.net-web-api, cors

The company I work for has two web applications and both have their own Web Api. The client side projects are written in AngularJs (version 1.6.9). Ever since the update to Google Chrome 65 my company's web applications that access a Web API are not longer working when executing `POST` and `PUT` methods. `GET` methods work fine.

This is the error message that I've started to get when I run my Web App locally since Chrome 65 when attempting to update an existing record using a `PUT` method:

[image: Console Errors - CORS issues]

[image: Network Header]

**PUT method code snippet**

```
managerFactory.updateIncidentRole = function (serviceUrl, data) {
    return $http.put(serviceUrl + 'api/Manager/UpdateIncidentRole', data);
};
```

Since our Web apps worked fine before the Chrome 65 update my investigation into this issue started at the release page for chrome 65 and I noticed a few people commented with CORS not working for their systems.

The first comment I came across:
[image: Nuke Dukem's comment about CORS policies]

The second comment I am across:
[image: Matteo Costantini's CORS issue]

The following code snippets are how both Web Api's are configured:

**WebApiConfig.cs**

```
var cors = new EnableCorsAttribute("*", "*", "*") { SupportsCredentials = true };
config.EnableCors(cors);
```

**Web.config**

```
  <system.web>
    <authentication mode="Windows" />
    <identity impersonate="true" />
  </system.web>
    <system.webServer>
        <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
        <handlers>
          <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
          <remove name="TRACEVerbHandler" />
          <remove name="OPTIONSVerbHandler" />
          <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="*" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
        </handlers>
    </system.webServer>
```

**Angular module config using $httpProvider to supply $http requests with credentials**

```
$httpProvider.defaults.withCredentials = true;
```

I'm at the end of my tether with this issue as I've been Googling CORS for the past week trying to understand what might be missing in order to get the Web apps working on Google Chrome again.

From the information I've supplied (and I'm happy enough to supply more upon request) what is missing?

Answer (score 0):

You can install IIS  Cors module and configure it

https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/iis-cors-module

Comment: I followed your link and ran the application from the download. I'm getting the following error message during the installation; This product did not install successfully: The IIS 7.0 CoreWebEnginer and W3SVC features must be installed to use Microsoft CORS Module.